# После запроса в бд вставляет 0

Tags: mysql, sql

После обработки формы вставляю запрос

```
UPDATE `users` SET `skype` = 'ukroficer', `icq` = '430858452', `jabber` = false WHERE `id` = '41'
```

и в поле `jabber` вставляется 0 , как избежать этого средствами mysql

Comment: попробуй так jabber = "false"

Comment: а хочется видеть false? булево поле - это просто integer поле. 0 - false, 1 (или любое не 0) - true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRUE и FALSE в MySQL заменяются на 1 и 0 соответственно, поскольку это всего лишь их синонимы.

Почитать подробнее можно **[здесь](http://sqle.ru/index.php/MySQL_Tutorial/Data_Types/Boolean)**.
Если хотите записать в ячейку именно это значение, возьмите его в кавычки.

Comment: нет мне нужно что бы не чего не вставляло или хотя бы null и нужно управлять именно с mysql

Comment: Все зависит от того, какой у вас тип поля. Вставляйте NULL или пустую строку.

Comment: так в в том и соль что хочу сделать это на стороне мускула, если ставлю null по умолчанию у поля, не помогает

Comment: Если нужет NULL, то и вставляйте NULL:  jabber = NULL